# Do not match any available overloads (FileURLWithPath)

Tags: url, avaudioplayer

I can't get this code to work, I keep getting an error saying:

> Argument labels '(FileURLWithPath:)' do not match any available
>   overloads

```
do {
    audioPlayer = try
        AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:
            URL(FileURLWithPath: sound!))
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Argument labels '(FileURLWithPath:)' do not match any available overloads` which is mentioned is quite remarkable.

Replace

```
AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(FileURLWithPath: sound!))
```

With

```
AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
```